# GET request error (Ruby on Rails with Angular)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby

I'm very new to web development, and maybe this is a silly mistake but I can't find the proper documentation for this.

I'm working on a **project with RoR and angular**: an online catalog for autoparts where the user can filter the products by giving certain information (brand, model, year, etc).

I already connnected the company database to RoR, have the model and controller (wich has a "select" query to the database) and can make consults from the rails console. I have an angular factory and a controller which is connected to the ruby controller and I can print the information of the database in the angular view.

The problem is when I try to pass the **params for an especific search** i get a GET **500 internal server error**.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong since I'm starting to learn. **Technically what I'm trying to do is to update the view to show the info based on the controller params given by the user**. I will leave some screenshots for major understanding.

My Angular module with factory and controller

```
angular.module('AppAutored', ['ngResource','ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap'])

    .factory("Product", function($resource) {
      return $resource("products/:id/:marca/:modelo/:anhio", { id: '@id', marca: '@marca', modelo: '@modelo', anhio: '@anhio'}, {
        index:   { method: 'GET', isArray: true, responseType: 'json' }
      });
    })

    .controller('MainCtrl', [
        '$scope',
        'Product',
        function($scope, Product) {
            $scope.getProducts = function () {
                $scope.products = Product.index({id: $scope.model_codigo});
            }

            $scope.clear =function(){
                $scope.filtro = {};
            };
        }
    ]);
```

Rails model for "products" table

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   #has_one :lineasprod
   self.table_name = "productos"
end
```

Rails controller, where i do the select to the database (and try to catch the params from angular controller (:codigo) and where I suppose is the error.

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
respond_to :json

def index
@products = Product.select("productos.cod_prod, lp.nombre as linea,              se.nombre as sistema, me.nombre as marca, mode.nombre as modelo, ae.año_equipos as anhio")
                   .where("productos.cod_prod = '(params[:codigo])' AND me.nombre = 'Honda' AND mode.nombre LIKE '%Accord%' AND pe.año_equipos = '2007'")
                   .joins("INNER JOIN lineas_productos  lp   ON lp.linea_producto  = productos.linea_producto
                           INNER JOIN sistemas_equipos  se   ON se.sistema_equipos = productos.sistema_equipos 
                           INNER JOIN productos_equipos pe   ON pe.cod_prod        = productos.cod_prod 
                           INNER JOIN marcas_equipos    me   ON me.marca_equipos   = pe.marca_equipos   
                           INNER JOIN modelos_equipos   mode ON pe.marca_equipos   = mode.marca_equipos AND mode.modelo_equipos = pe.modelo_equipos
                           INNER JOIN años_equipos      ae   ON pe.año_equipos     = ae.año_equipos")
                   .first(250)
respond_with(@products)
end

end
```

routes file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

resources :products, defaults: { format: 'json' }
root to: 'application#angular'

#get 'index/products/:codigo' => "products#index"
```

application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :exception

respond_to :json

def angular
  render 'products/index'
end

def show
  render 'products/index'
end


def set_csrf_cookie_for_ng
  cookies['XSRF-TOKEN'] = form_authenticity_token if protect_against_forgery?
end

protected

def verified_request?
  super || valid_authenticity_token?(session, request.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'])
end

end
```

The error I get when try to search an id:
[image: The error I get when try to search an id]

Comment: Do you have `app/views/products/index.html.erb`?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `app/views/products/index.jbuilder`

Comment: You should show the error in the server logs. You're currently just showing the error in the developer console, which doesn't have much useful information other than telling you that the server encountered _some_ error. BTW text is preferred to screenshots here

Comment: I do not have that file. Whats supposed to be on it? Sorry for such silly question.

Comment: Tomorrow first hour will post the image from the serverlog. Thank you. Oh and btw i tried to screenshot all but it wont let me put more than 1 since i just made the account.

Comment: [The server log when i try to search] (http://imgur.com/X75YvgJ)

As you can see, im only trying with one parameter (the product id) for test pruposes.

Comment: On the productsController, if i replace the `productos.cod_prod = '(params[:codigo])'` with `productos.cod_prod = '10-10778'` it works perfectly, im just trying it to be dinamic.(The user could search any id by typing it)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    @products = Product.select(...)
    render json: @products
  end

end
```